# rails 4 acts as commentable reply link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using acts_as_commentable to nest post - comments- reply. Is there any one who can give me good examples especially on the comments controller and post show view. I appreciate for your help.

Comment: whoever voted this question down, please explain why. This new user should be given the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Can you post an example of your code so far please.

Answer (score 0):

This is model/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  belongs_to :user

  def self.build_from(obj, user_id, comment)
    new \
      :commentable => obj,
      :body        => comment,
      :user_id     => user_id
  end

  def has_children?
    self.children.any?
  end

  scope :find_comments_by_user, lambda { |user|
    where(:user_id => user.id).order('created_at DESC')
  }

  scope :find_comments_for_commentable, lambda { |commentable_str, commentable_id|
    where(:commentable_type => commentable_str.to_s, :commentable_id => commentable_id).order('created_at DESC')
  }

  def self.find_commentable(commentable_str, commentable_id)
    commentable_str.constantize.find(commentable_id)
  end

  def owner?(user)
    if user.present?
      return self.user_id == user.id
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

This is show in controller

```
@comments = @project.comment_threads.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page])

@new_comment = Comment.build_from(@project, @user.id, '')
```

This is your form

```
= simple_form_for comment, remote: true do |f|
    = f.input :body, input_html: { rows: '2' }, label: 'Content'
    = f.input :commentable_id, as: :hidden, value: comment.commentable_id
    = f.input :commentable_type, as: :hidden, value: comment.commentable_type
    = f.button :submit, 'Done', class: 'btn btn-primary', disable_with: 'Submitting…'
```

According to method build_from(obj, user_id, comment), in your comment_controller#create:

```
@user = current_user
@comment_hash = params[:comment]
@obj = @comment_hash[:commentable_type].constantize.find(@comment_hash[:commentable_id])
@comment = Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, @comment_hash[:body])
@comment.save
```

That's all, hop it helpfull